# Xpath searching for element inside a string rather than the entire thing

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom, domparser

I'm using simple html dom parser and i'm trying to get the company name from the following string:

```
<a data-omniture="LIST:COMPANYNAME" href="/b/Elite+Heating+and+Plumbing+Services-Plumbers-Reading-RG46RA-901196207/index.html" itemprop="name"> Elite Heating &amp; Plumbing Services </a>
```

So the bit in between the a tags.

I have the following code:

```
<?php include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.thelink.com/');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; echo '</ul>';

?
```

Also, is it posible to search for html5 data things, so data-whatever: the info in the link

Which brings all the links back, but obviously i don't want all the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would just do:

```
$name = $html->find('a[itemprop=name]', 0)->text();
```

This isn't xpath btw, it's css.